# Dynamic set text in GWT Label

Tags: gwt, label

I want to set text of `GWT Label` dynamically.

For example I am using below code to set text in `GWT Label` :

```
Label statusLabel = new Label();

    for (int i = 0; i < numX; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numY; ++j) {        
         statusLabel.setText("Processing " + "(" + (i + 1) + "/" + (j + 1)  + " of " + numX + "/" + numY + ") ...");
        }
     }
```

And I add this `Label` in RootPanel one time like this : `RootPanel.get().add(statusLabel);`

But problem is that `Label` text is unchnage.

What I missed? Or How can set dynamic text into GWT `Lable`.

Comment: Are you running the loop before the label is actually attached to the parent?

Comment: No. First I added the label into RootPanel and after then I use the above for loop.

Comment: Is the final text the result after the loop should end?

Comment: @OviFaur No. Text is change in the loop depends on the value of i and j. And I need to show dynamic change TEXT in the label.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty What does the label actually show (what's the text) when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is just to fast. It does not allow the browser to render the changed text. If your processing is running just inside that loop, the generated JavaScript code will be executed as a single block and will not allow the UI to refresh in-between.

To allow the UI to refresh, you need to use [delayed logic](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html).
For example using [`Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred(com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand)).
Deferred means here the JavaScript code returns control to the browser, which refreshes the text, and afterwards the [`ScheduledCommand`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.ScheduledCommand.html) gets executed.

*To make it short:*
Split up your processing in different parts, where each of them changes the text and gets scheduled using a [`ScheduledCommand`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.ScheduledCommand.html).
As an alternative you could keep a counter variable in your class (like in the loop) and just re-schedule [`ScheduledCommands`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.ScheduledCommand.html) until your processing is finished.

*Just keep in mind that the browser needs some time to refresh the text and that it won't do that until your JavaScript code returns.*